# How to prefill input box with future date in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to prefill an input field with a future date in a django template.

```
<input name="expiration_date" class="form-control" id="expiration_date" type="text"
                                           data-toggle="input-mask" data-mask-format="0000-00-00" value="{{ object.table.expiration_date|default:'' }}"
```

How could I set it so `object.table.expiration_date|default:''` is prefilled with datetime.now() plus 30 days?

Comment: try using timedelta .. something like this ....  datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **default filter**, you should write a **custom filter** :

```
# my_filters.py

import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name=exp_date)
def expiration_default(value):
    if not value:
        return  datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    else:
        return value
```

Your app layout might look like this:

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        my_filters.py
    views.py
```

Then you can use it in your template:

```
<input name="expiration_date" class="form-control" 
id="expiration_date" type="text"
data-toggle="input-mask" data-mask-format="0000-00-00" 
value="{{ object.table.expiration_date|exp_date }}"
```

Also dont forget to add following tag in your template:

```
{% load  my_filters.py %}
```

refer to   [documentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)